# Kinematics of an particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle describes motion, which is described by the following formula:

$\vec{r}(t) = (2t^2+5)\vec{i} + (\cos(t^2)-3)\vec{j}
$

I am asked two questions as to what is the total distance travelled between $t_1$
and $t_2$ [and] what is the equation of motion $f(x)$

Actually, I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me?

In some manuals of Elementary Physics, I have read that in order to find the total distance on the curve: one has to derive with respect to the velocity vector module. But, I am not very sure about this proposition. Therefore, I would like someone to tell me how to do it (and if he could base his explanation on some example, then better).

With regard to the second question, I have tried to clear the time of the second component and replace it in the first component. In order to arrive at a simple mathematical function that can be sketched to see graphically what the particle displacement is like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kinematics of a particle (two dimensions)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431904/kinematics-of-a-particle-two-dimensions)